# Android Onclicking textView the editText comes without numpad.How to get the numpad on single click on textView?

Tags: android

I have a textview.On clicking the texstview the edit text comes up with focus. But to get the numpad another click is required.

I want that when i click on TextView,the edit text should come up with the numpad togeter withoutanother click on the editText.Not through xml.But manually
In the xml i have already given it as android:inputType="number"
(the text view is made invisible on click)

The on click method----
case R.id.txtPhoneNo:

```
        hintPhoneNum.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        phoneNum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        edtPhoneNum.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        edtPhoneNum.requestFocus();
        edtPhoneNum.setText("");
```

WHen the editText gets focus how to get the numpad forcefully?

The correct answer is 
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

Comment: As it happens, I think that Maver1ck has given you the answer that you need, but in future, you should give more information as to what you've tried. For this problem, I would recommend a google search before simply posting a very short question on SO - as it doesn't take any digging at all to find the answer that was posted. Alternatively, Android has a very good website containing documentation for all of their classes, including xml attributes for widgets (which, surprisingly enough, includes the inputType for EditTexts

Comment: Sorry if you did not understand the question.In the xml it already there.The problem is that you have to click twice

Answer (score 1):

for your EditText add the following XML:

```
 android:inputType="number"
```

**EDIT**

Try requesting focus just after your textView was set invisible:

```
yourTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //or View.GONE
yourEditText.requestFocus();
```

This should display the keypad immediately

Comment: want that when i click on TextView,the edit text should come up with the numpad togeter withoutanother click on the editText.Not through xml.But manually In the xml i have already given it as android:inputType="number" (the text view is made invisible on click)

Comment: hintPhoneNum.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   phoneNum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   edtPhoneNum.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   edtPhoneNum.requestFocus();
   edtPhoneNum.setText("");

Comment: This is what i have at present. Onclick of text view

Answer (score 0):

when `TextView` is shown or `touched` first it gets `focus` and when you `click` on it again it performs `onClick()` so you have to handle Foucus of TextView to achieve what you want.

Comment: umm yes or you can call onClick() on onFocusChange()

Comment: How can you forcefully get the numpad?

Comment: i know how to hide it forcefully

Comment: InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);

Comment: <requestFocus /> in your edittext xml it will automatically take focus and show keyboard